# How to use jooq to update table when column names and it's values determined at runtime

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I have list of table column names and it's values which will be determined @ run time. Right now I am using following way to achieve the feet which requires casting `Filed` to `TableField` for every single column name. Is there any better way ?

```
override fun updateFields(job: Job, jsonObject: JsonObject, handler: Handler<AsyncResult<Job?>>): JobQService {


    val updateFieldsDsl = dslContext.update(JOB)

    var feildSetDsl: UpdateSetMoreStep<*>? = null

    jsonObject.map.keys.forEach { column ->
        feildSetDsl = if (feildSetDsl == null) {
            updateFieldsDsl.set(JOB.field(column) as TableField<Record, Any>, jsonObject.getValue(column))
        } else {
            feildSetDsl!!.set(JOB.field(column) as TableField<Record, Any>, jsonObject.getValue(column))
        }
    }

    val queryDsl = feildSetDsl!!.where(JOB.ID.eq(job.id))

    jdbcClient.rxUpdateWithParams(queryDsl.sql, JsonArray(queryDsl.bindValues)).subscribeBy(
            onSuccess = { handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(job)) },
            onError = { handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(it)) }

    )

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "better" but there is a method [`UpdateSetStep.set(Map)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdateSetStep.html#set-java.util.Map-), which seems to be helpful for what you're trying to do. See the javadoc:

> UpdateSetMoreStep set(Map<?,?> map)
>
> Set a value for a field in the UPDATE statement.
>   Keys can either be of type String, Name, or Field.
>
> Values can either be of type <T> or Field<T>. jOOQ will attempt to convert values to their corresponding field's type.

Comment: @NagarajuNooka: Cool, glad I could help!